# Enumeration option task

Tags: enumerate, tasks

When I update Miktex 2.9 I have problem with enumeration option task. When I print:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@mynum#1{\ifcase#1\or a\or b\or v\or g\or d\or d1\or e\or zh
\or z\or i\or j\or k\or l\or lj\or m\or n\or nj\or o\or p\or r
\or s\or t\or c1\or u\or f\or h\or c\or ch\or d2\or sh\else ?\fi}
\NewPatternFormat{m}{\@mynum}
\makeatother

\settasks{
  %label-width = 2.7em ,
  %item-indent = 2em ,
  before-skip = -\parskip-2mm ,
  after-skip = -\parskip-2mm ,
  after-item-skip = -\parskip
}

\begin{tasks}[counter-format=tsk[m])](3)
        \task 2;
        \task 1;
        \task 0.
    \end{tasks}
```

then I have answer

Undefined control sequence.
l.46 \NewPatternFormat
                      {m}{@mynum}

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: `counter-format` was replaced with the `label` option with the update of the `tasks` package to version `1.0`.

Comment: Could you please add a small description of the desired output?

Comment: I want alphabet cyrilic like a) б) в) г) ... now I got a) b) v) g) ...

Comment: Does `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\settasks{
  before-skip = -\parskip-2mm ,
  after-skip = -\parskip-2mm ,
  after-item-skip = -\parskip, 
  label=\asbuk*)
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}[](3)
        \task 2;
        \task 1;
        \task 0.
    \end{tasks}
    
\end{document}` result in the desired output?

Comment: I try your suggestion but I have got Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \abx@aux@refcontext
                       {anyt/global//global/global} and I use serbian babel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an up to date `tasks` use the `label` option and define your command analoguous to `\alph`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\makeatletter
\def\@mynum#1{\ifcase#1\or a\or b\or v\or g\or d\or d1\or e\or zh
\or z\or i\or j\or k\or l\or lj\or m\or n\or nj\or o\or p\or r
\or s\or t\or c1\or u\or f\or h\or c\or ch\or d2\or sh\else ?\fi}
\newcommand*\mynum[1]{\expandafter\@mynum\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}[label=\mynum*)](3)
  \task 2;
  \task 1;
  \task 0.
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

However, from what I read in the comments it looks to me you are trying to re-invent the wheel?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}[label=\asbuk*)](3)
  \task 2;
  \task 1;
  \task 0.
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Everything work as you show, thank you very much!

Comment: @BranislavM you're welcome